# Get hashtags from string, replace some symbols in it and convert it to link PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, hashtag

I have some string with hashtags looks like @user_name.
Now i convert all hashtags to links this way:

```
$text = preg_replace ("/@(\\w+)/", '<a href="http://$1.'.SITE_NAME.'">@$1</a> ', $text);
```

As you can see, all hashtags becomes to subdomain names. If you know, there some problems with `_` symbol in subdomain names (some browsers not supports that, IE supports, but not set cookies, etc..). So i need to replace the `_` symbols in subdomain to `-` (minus), but keep `_` symbols in hashtag view. There link what i need to `<a href="http://user-name.site.com">@user_name</a>`. How?

Comment: A hash tag is `#`. Surely you mean the `at` sign (`@`)

Comment: @BeatAlex i think it does not matter in this case

Comment: Well no, it's still do-able whether it's a `#` or a `@`, but you're asking for a hash-tag which was where I was getting confused, as there aren't any in your code.

Comment: @BeatAlex maybe you'll think it strange, but in Soviet Russia we call both # and @ tags in text as "hashtags". =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace_callback () like this:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback ("/@(\\w+)/", function ($matches) {
    return '<a href="http://'. str_replace('_', '-', $matches[1]) .'.abc.com.">'.$matches[1].'</a> '; },  "test @user_john here");
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i know new php function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you already have an answer...

I was going to suggest this regex to use:

`(https?:..[^\.]*)(_)([^\.]*)`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/zF8aJ4)